# Raspbian keeps erasing from sd card

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I left a raspberry( which I'm connected to using ssh on  PUTTY)   to run an apt-get dist-upgrade. After ten minutes the raspberry connection has been aborted and I was unable to reconnect to.

---

Almost all the OS files are missing on the card. there are only 3 (.txt) files remaining

Could someone explain to me what happened

PS : it is a 16GB SD CARD

Comment: What are you using to view your sd card?

Comment: I m using a micro sd to sd  card adapter

Comment: In a Windows PC or Mac? If so they won't see the linux partition.

Comment: Ah i didn't understand you hahaha !!!! I am using a Windows PC. There is a green led on the raspberry which I think indicates that the processor is executing something . It used to glow  but it don't do that anymore

Comment: Why are we able to see those files first when the sd card flashing ended ?